# How to get hdmi input/output of mx android box?

Tags: android, television, hdmi, hdcp

I'm using the tv remote to command up,down,left and right,I want the tv to communicate in the MX android box using hdmi. Anyone knows how to do it, or any link that could help?

Answer (score 1):

xbmc does it - on linux - with "libcec". You are looking for HDMI-CEC on Android.
have a look here: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=CEC.

Also a xmbc android port exists, so I would start to search from there. Good luck!

Comment: i dont use xbmc, i have my own app to be run... is there any docu/api on it?

Comment: the suggestion is to look how xbmc does it, since it is open source. furthermore you can find many links in the xbmc wiki like http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMC_for_Android_specific_FAQ (look for "CEC") and digging in the sources. I would start to see whether your device supports it at all.

Comment: hmm yeah i actually find a source code on it, im reading it now, still learning how to implement it... thanks :)

Comment: @joy are you able to do it? get screen in a app.